# Sourcing variables as local in bash

Tags: bash, variables, import, local

I've got a bash file where are defined a number of variables:

```
VAR1="value1"
VAR2="value2"
# ...
```

I need to *import* these variables in `~/.bashrc` in order to customize `PS1`, `PATH` and so on, but don't want that the imported variables can be accessed outside of `~/.bashrc`.

To make myself clear with an example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
function setPATH
{
    local . ~/bashvars.sh # this isn't legal, of course...
    PATH="$PATH:$VAR1"    # $VAR1 is defined in ~/bashvars.sh
    unset -f setPATH
}
setPATH
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a subshell:

```
getPATH() (
    . ~/bashvars.sh
    echo "$PATH:$VAR1"
)
PATH=$(getPATH)
```